# An example of a map that is continuous in the Zariski topology but not regular.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

An exercise in Smith's Algebraic Geometry book says:

> Give an example of a map $f: \mathbb{A^n} \to  \mathbb{A^m}$ that is continuous in the Zariski topology but not regular.

I attempt but my solution was incorrect so I check the solution which is:

> Set $n = m = 1$. In this case, the Zarski-closed sets are finite sets of points or the empty set or all of $\mathbb{A^n}$. The map that swaps two points (like 1 and 2) but leaves all other points fixed is Zarski-continuous, but is clearly not regular.

I don't understand the solution. Why is a map that switches only two points a continuous map? And why is this map not regular?

Answer (score 1):

Call $f$ to the function swapping both points $p_1\neq p_2$, we only need to check that for any closed subset $X$ of $\mathbb{A}^1$ the preimage $f^{-1}(X)$ is a closed subset. The only closed subsets of the affine line are $\emptyset, \{q_1,\dots,q_l\}$ and $\mathbb{A}^1$. So, the sets $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{A}^1$ are done, and we have $f^{-1}(\{q_1,\dots,q_l\})=\{q_1,\dots,q_l\}$ if $p_1$ or $p_2$ do not belong to $\{q_1,\dots,q_l\}$ or if both are in it. Now if $p_1=q_1$ we have $f^{-1}(\{p_1,\dots,q_l\})=\{p_2,\dots,q_l\}$ , similarly if $p_2 \in \{q_1,\dots,q_l\}$. In any case preimages of closed sets are closed too.

On the other side, $f$ could not be regular because a regular (polynomial) function $f(x)\in k[x]$ been $f(x)=x$ such that $f(q_1)=q_2$ a $f(q_2)=q_1$ does not exists.